# Using GitHub's REST API to list public repos from my external site deletes my token

Tags: javascript, github, github-api

I am trying to list my GitHub public repos on my public website using their REST API. I have been creating personal tokens so far. In localhost it works.

When I do the request from my site it responds a **401** and it **deletes** my token.

To get the repos I am doing this simple request:

```js
async function loadRepositories() {
  const token = 'my_token';

  const response = await fetch("https://api.github.com/users/tauromachian/repos",
    {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    }
  );
  const repositories = await response.json();

  return repositories;
},
```

How can I get this done?

Comment: what's the error? also you shouldn't make a PAT public...

Comment: @DanielA.White I explained the error in the question. Also, what's a PAT?

Comment: personal access token.

Comment: @DanielA.White In the real code I get the token from the environment. I simplified that for this question.

Comment: Are you checking the PAT into the repository?  If so, GitHub may very well be automatically expiring it depending on certain policies because that's not secure, so don't do that.

Comment: Which HTTP status code do you get? 401? You shouldn't make the request on the client side as you will need to provide the personal access token there. Instead make the request on the server side and call your server endpoint from your public client. This way you won't expose the PAT. Probably Github deletes the token as it notices you are publicly exposing the PAT for your own security.

Comment: @Mushroomator Will do

Comment: @DanielA.White Updated my question to include the exact error. I do think it's expiring it in some manner.

Comment: @Mushroomator So, I can't get the repos directly from GitHub?

Comment: Once you do that, it should work.

Comment: @Mushroomator You may as well make that the answer given that there won't be any other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Github is trying to protect you from someone stealing your identity here. There are [ways to detect if a HTTP request is sent from the browser or a server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20222111/how-to-tell-if-a-request-comes-from-browser-or-server) (it's not 100% reliable though).

As you make the request from the browser which is a public client, meaning everyone can read the code and hence secrets you use within the code you are exposing your Personal Access Token (PAT). This PAT identifies you against Github, therefore if someone else could get hold of it, they can impersonate you and e.g. delete repos, steal code etc. (if the token has the correct scopes).
As Github wants to prevent that from happening, they delete tokens which are publicly exposed (they know it's exposed as the the request comes from a browser). Therefore attacks like that are not possible anymore.

To make your website work however you can simply make the request from your server as you can securely store secrets on the server-side and call the endpoint of your server from your website. Once you do that, Github won't delete the token, your token is save and you can display the data on the website.